# Xpath grep child and replace with top element

Tags: java, xpath

im trying to resolve a problem to get childnodes one level up and remove the old attributes with childs.

My xml looks like this:

```
<results>    
<result id="6f6d6f1f-1c9f-4f3f-b77a-0430504c6626">
    <name>TCP timestamps</name>
    <host>192.168.0.1
        <asset asset_id="cb779852-fa5f-4097-ba57-2f202c04bf68"/>
    </host>
    <port>general/tcp</port>
    <nvt oid="1.3.6.1.4.1.25623.1.0.80091">
        <xref>URL:http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1323.txt</xref>
        <tags>cvss_base_vector=AV:N/AC:H/Au:N/C:P/I:N/A:N|summary=The remote host implements TCP timestamps and
            therefore allows to compute
            the uptime.|vuldetect=Special IP packets are forged and sent with a little delay in between to the
            target IP. The responses are searched for a timestamps. If found, the timestamps are
            reported.|solution=To disable TCP timestamps on linux add the line 'net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps = 0' to
            /etc/sysctl.conf. Execute 'sysctl -p' to apply the settings at runtime.

            To disable TCP timestamps on Windows execute 'netsh int tcp set global timestamps=disabled'

            Starting with Windows Server 2008 and Vista, the timestamp can not be completely disabled.

            The default behavior of the TCP/IP stack on this Systems is to not use the
            Timestamp options when initiating TCP connections, but use them if the TCP peer
            that is initiating communication includes them in their synchronize (SYN) segment.

            See also: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9152|affected=TCP/IPv4 implementations
            that implement RFC1323.|insight=The remote host implements TCP timestamps, as defined by
            RFC1323.|impact=A side effect of this feature is that the uptime of the remote
            host can sometimes be computed.|solution_type=Mitigation|qod_type=remote_banner
        </tags>
        <cert/>
    </nvt>
    <threat>Low</threat>
    <severity>2.6</severity>
    <description>It was detected that the host implements RFC1323.

        The following timestamps were retrieved with a delay of 1 seconds in-between:
        Packet 1: 2961998095
        Packet 2: 1703213053
    </description>
    <overrides/>
</result>
```

So i want to remove  but need the child . What can i do to replace nvt with tags?  must be on same level as name, host, port etc.. Is there a function like replace? How could i solve this, im trying that before:

```
 NodeList cleanNodeList0 = null;
    try {
        cleanNodeList0 = (NodeList) xpath.compile("//result/nvt/tags").evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    NodeList cleanNodeList4 = null;
    try {
        cleanNodeList4 = (NodeList) xpath.compile("//result/nvt").evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (int i = cleanNodeList4.getLength() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        cleanNodeList4.item(i).getParentNode().removeChild(cleanNodeList4.item(i));
        cleanNodeList4.item(i).appendChild(cleanNodeList0.item(i));
    }
```

Comment: Cut the tags text on the example to improve readability and post an xml sample of the expected output please.

Answer (score 0):

XPath can never modify your XML structure: you would normally build the new tree in XSLT (or in Java if you enjoy low-level coding).

I can't work out what your exact requirements are from existing code that (presumably) doesn't meet them.